# Win10 1809 Cumulative Updates not working due to version being too old

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-v1809, windows-10-1809

I have a machine that is running Windows 10 v1890 Build 17763.805, which is apparently too old to take the latest cumulative updates (CU), as that CU doesn't even recognize that old a version/the pre-reqs aren't present.

Is there any way to tell which CU jumps I can make without getting the following error:

> This update is not applicable to your computer.

I would like to avoid having to download each and every monthly CU from .805 forward.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First you have to evaluate why the updates cannot be applied. For this you have to look at the CBS logs in the folder C:\Windows\logs.

Comment: Do you receive the same after running in an Admin terminal `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`?

Answer (score 0):

Do a Windows 10 Repair Install process and use the first selection to upgrade your operating system. That will bring you to "now" 20H2 version.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Upgrade button (not Download Button) and select Run.

This will download the new version and install it. Everything will be kept. Do watch for that option during the process.